# WPF - RibbonWindow - Borderless Theme with Quick Access Toolbar

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, infragistics, ribbon-control

I am trying to use a RibbonWindow with some ribbon controls.

I am using a RibbonWindow. Out of the box, it shows up with the default windows 7 title bar. (ofcourse, I'm on Win7). The title bar also has the quick access toolbar buttons when enabled.

I want to make a Custom Border with my own close buttons. I tried applying a regular Window's Borderless style, targetting the RibbonWindow. Sure it becomes borderless (i.e., my custom border appears), but i am LOSING the quick access toolbar which appears on the title bar by default in the RibbonWindow.

How can I include the quick access toolbar buttons in my custom border for RibbonWindow?